# Add text in a Matplotlib plot without y-coordinates

Tags: python, matplotlib

For a personal project, I'd like to add a text in the upper right corner of the plot but as I'm displaying horizontal bars, I don't have y-coordinates and thus, I can't use either `plt.text()`or `ax.annotate()`as they require a y-coordinates.

Here is a picture of the plot I'm having :
[image: What I have]

and here is what I would like to have (with **text on the upper-left corner**):
[image: The objective]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `text`. And the coordinates "still exist". See the following example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.subplots()
names = ["a", "b", "c"]
val = [23, 17, 5]
ax.barh(names, val)

ax.text(0.8, 0.95, "text 1", transform = ax.transAxes)
ax.text(20, 0, "text 2", transform = ax.transData)
ax.text(20, 2, "text 3", transform = ax.transData)

plt.show()
```

Resulting in:
[image]

See also:
https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.text.html
https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/advanced/transforms_tutorial.html